# How to use IPython Notebook Widget interact() with a heavy computation matplotlib plot?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, interactive, matplotlib-widget

How to prevent computation of function inside interact while clicking the mouse and only get the result after releasing it?

The problem is I have a plot that takes around 10s to compute and it depends on a real valued parameter. I want the slider to be take float values but whenever I try to change the slider it will still compute the plot for intermediate values of the slider.

It would be nice if there is an option such that it only computes the function after releasing the mouse.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I settled with using `interact_manual`, instead of `interact`

Comment: Not ideal but can solve part of my problem! Thank you!